# Not Able to get the return value

Tags: c++

i am using this function to read from a notepad file and fill the data in `char str[255]` but after I execute the function `str` is still empty.

```
char str[255];

char* data_pull()
{
    std::ifstream in("C:/myfile.txt");
    if(!in){
        printf("\nCannot open the file");
       exit (1);
    }

    while(in){
        in.getline(str, 255);  
       printf(str);
    }

    in.close();
    return str;
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `printf(str)`? BTW, **never** use `printf(str)` for str read from external input, since str might contain formatting code like "%s", better use `puts(str)` or `printf("%s", str)`. How do you see that the string returned is empty? Just a question aside: could it be that the last line in the text is an empty line?

Comment: printf(str) is giving me the right output but when i use str in some other function than i get to know that str is empty

Comment: @sumit kang: This happens because your file ends in an empty line, so the last value stored in `str` is that empty line. Nothing strange here.

Answer (score 4):

With `in.getline(str, 255);` you keep overwriting `str` for every line in the input file: in other words, every line will overwrite the previous line stored in `str`.

If the file ends with an empty line, then `str` will store an empty string at the end of the loop.

Comment: Not quite correct; I've tested the code on a file with a non-empty last line, and the buffer is still empty.

Comment: @csl: The file you used had *empty* last line. You simply didn't realize that. If the last "line" in your file ends with end-of-line marker (platform-specific, like CR+LF on Windows), then your file has one more line that is empty and is followed by `<EOF>`. If you want to create a file with truly non-empty last line, you need a file that has no end-of-line marker at the end of the last line, like "SomeData<EOF>". Have you tried that?

Comment: @AndreyT `vim` didn't show any trailing newline, but sure enough `echo -ne "hello\nworld" > test` worked out allright.  Thanks.